Proof of bijection between $S_1(R,\underline{R})$ and the set of cuts in $(R,<)$
Hi guys I am trying to solve the following exercise but without great success and I hope you can help me:
"Let $\underline{R}$ be a real closed field (RCF). Show that $S_1(R,\underline{R})$ is in one to one correspondence with the set of cuts in $(R,<)$. (Where for the purposes of this exercise, a cut in $(R,<)$ is  a downward closed proper subset $A$ of $R$ without greatest element)"
Here is what I thought so far:
First of all, if I interpreted well the text of the exercise, the set of cuts $C$ is the set with elements the sets of the form $C_r =\{x\in R: r\leq x\}$ where $r\in R$.
Now, as for $S_1(R,\underline{R})$, since RCF has  quantifier elimination (QE), then every type $p(x)\in S_1(R,\underline{R})$ is uniquely determined by the atomic formulas that it contains. This means that every type $p(x)$ can contain at most one formula of the form $x=r$ (if it were to contain two different formulas $x=r_1$ and $x=r_2$ it would be unsatisfiable). I will refer to this kind of types as $p_r(x)$ to underline the fact that it contains the formula $x=r$.
The remaining cases are among the types that contains all the formulas $x\neq r$ for all $r\in R$. Now I am kinda stuck and I ask you guys these questions:

Is everything I said so far correct? Is this the right path?
How do I characterize the latter kind of types I listed?
How do I conclude the exercise? I.e. how do I create the bijection between the sets? Because if the characterizations I gave of the $p_r(x)$'s and of $C$ are correct, I would simply send each $p_r(x)$ to the set $C_r=\{x\in R : r\leq x\}$ and that would be it.

Any help is very much appreciated :)

Your set $C_r$ is upwards-closed, not downwards-closed. The elements of $R$ do determine cuts: ${x\in R\mid x<r}$. But there are many other cuts which are not of this form.

What is the definition of the notation $S_1(R,\underline{R})$? And what is $R$?

I denote by $S_1(R,\underline{R})$ the set of all complete $n$-types over R in $\underline{R}$ where with $R$ I refer to the support of the structure $\underline{R}$.

Could you please expand on the first comment? My $C_r$ is equal to the interval $[r,\infty)$ isn't that downward close?

No: "$C$ is downwards-closed" means that if $b\in C$ and $a<b$, then $a\in C$.

oh, I see, then I was very much wrong. Thank you for correcting me, do you have any idea on how to conclude the proof? So what is the general form of the cuts?

You're on the right track, you just need to think a bit harder about what QE gives you.
Let $p(x)$ be a complete $1$-type over $R$. As you noted, there are two cases:

If some formula of the form $x = r$ is in $p$, then $p$ is the realized type $\mathrm{tp}(r/R)$.
If not, then $x\neq r$ is in $p$ for all $r\in R$. Then for every $r\in R$, either $x<r$ or $r<x$ is in $p$ (but not both). Let $C = \{r\in R\mid (r<x)\in p\}$. Note that $C$ is a
downwards-closed subset of $R$, in the sense that if $r\in C$ and
$r'<r$, then $r'\in C$.

Conversely, for any downwards-closed $C\subseteq R$, we can consider the type $\{x\neq r\mid r\in R\}\cup \{r<x\mid r\in C\}\cup\{x<r\mid r\notin C\}$. By compactness, this is consistent, and by QE it is complete, so it determines a unique $1$-type over $R$.
Altogether, we have shown that the set of $1$-types over $R$ is in bijection with $R\cup \mathcal{C}$, where $\mathcal{C}$ is the set of downwards closed subsets of $R$.
It's reasonable to call a downwards-closed subset of $R$ a "cut". But this disagrees with the definition you've been given (a cut corresponding to a type may have a greatest element, and it may not be a proper subset). The problem as you've stated it also seems to have disregarded the realized types.
